# Confusion using strtok

Tags: c, strtok

Im using `strtok` and getting a little confused.

I have an array holding a lot of strings and I want to tokenize the strings into a temporary array. When i perform the strtok it stored the first token in the temporary array, but also changed the original arrays value. So im pretty confused.

```
char cmdTok[10] , *cmd = cmdTok;
printf("command[0] = %s\n", commands[0]);
cmd = strtok(commands[0], " \n\0");
printf("command[0] after strtok = %s\n", commands[0]);
```

Output being

```
command[0] = #Draw A Ring
command[0] after strtok = #draw
```

How do i retain the original values in command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the `strtok` on a copy of the string.

```
char *copy = strdup(commands[0]);
cmd = strtok(copy, " \n");
/* ... */

free(copy);
```

If you don't have / want to use `strdup`:

```
char *copy = malloc(strlen(commands[0]) + 1);
strcpy(copy, commands[0]);
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` modifies its input.

It's a bad old function. Sorry.

If you want to both preserve the original and call `strtok` (instead of `strstr` or another such alternative), you're going to have to copy the string out before the first call.